# Cannot Connect to Database Master at SQL Server - SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, installation, sql

I have a following setup:

subnet is the same, two separate VMs
First server has SQL Server 2017 RTM
Second server has SharePoint 2019 Enterprise

After installing SharePoint, I get the following error:
Cannot Connect to Database Master at SQL Server at SRV-DB02. The Database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it

What have I done recently?

- Installed SQL Server 2019 with the appropriate roles, domain account called SQLAdmin is set for SQL Server Service and SQL Agent Service, in the installation this user was set as an SQL Administrator, along with SPAdmin (SharePoint Admin user)
- Same users are set in Analysis Service step
- After the installation, these users were granted dbcreator, sysadmin and securityadmin roles
- Same was repeated with SQL Server 2017 RTM (just in case if the version wasn't correctly installed, which I really do not believe) - same result
- Firewall was turned off for test (both Domain and Private Profiles), telnet connection worked to 1433, 2382 and 2383 ports. Telnet also worked while Firewall was turned on (so the rule is properly configured)
- TCP/IP and Named Pipe is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager
- All services were in Running state (SQL Server Browser, Agent and SQL Server itself)

What have I missed in these steps?

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have done an overall troubleshoot, I would suggest you to follow the steps provided by this article to check it again:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36615.sharepoint-troubleshooting-cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server.aspx

Comment: I am checking this thread, if there is any update, welcome to post back.